# How to preserve Python Syntax when inputting data to another Python file in Linux?

Tags: python, linux

There's the script1.py, which is set to send its output to file1.py:

```
python script1.py > file1.py
```

The content of file1.py is:

```
19/11/2020 19:40:17
['MGLU3', 'VIVT4', 'EQTL3']
['R$ 24,64', 'R$ 46,39', 'R$ 21,12']
```

Then there's the script2.py:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]
with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()
result = list(zip(lines[1],lines[2]))
print(result)
```

When I use file1.py content as an input to script2.py as:

```
python script2.py file1.py
```

I got:

```
[('[', '['), ("'", "'"), ('M', 'R'), ('G', '$'), ('L', ' '), ('U', '2'), ('3', '4'), ("'", ','), (',', '6'), (' ', '4'), ("'", "'"), ('V', ','), ('I', ' '), ('V', "
'"), ('T', 'R'), ('4', '$'), ("'", ' '), (',', '4'), (' ', '6'), ("'", ','), ('E', '3'), ('Q', '9'), ('T', "'"), ('L', ','), ('3', ' '), ("'", "'"), (']', 'R'), ('\
n', '$')]
```

In summary, the script2.py is splitting each value of file1.py content. I'd like to just "match" the lists as:

```
[('MGLU3', 'R$ 24,64'), ('VIVT4','R$ 46,39'), ('EQTL3', 'R$ 21,12')]
```

Is there any way I could read the content of file1 "preserving" the Python Syntax? Of course there's the option of handling the huge list I got, but I was wondering if there's a more simple option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import sys
from ast import literal_eval

inFile = sys.argv[1]
with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()
result = list(zip(literal_eval(lines[1]),literal_eval(lines[2])))
print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('MGLU3', 'R$ 24,64'), ('VIVT4', 'R$ 46,39'), ('EQTL3', 'R$ 21,12')]
```